# User selects random excel cell, clicks button, macro executes - Bloomberg DDE

Tags: excel, bloomberg, dde

I am rather new to macros and new to this forum. I searched the forums and have not found the answer I am looking for. I am writing a macro to launch Bloomberg DDE so when a button is clicked, a terminal window will come to the front with the specific syntax already submitted.

for general sake, let's say that $B$3 = MSFT, $H$2=CSCO, $E$9=GIS

if the user selects MSFT on the spreadsheet and then clicks on the GIP30 button, I want the following sent to the BB terminal:

MSFT  GIP30

So in addition to the macro identifying what cell was selected, 'US' may need to be appended before being transmitted to BB DDE. I have take some tidbits from around the web.

Got it to work when I hardcoded "MSFT US", but need it to be dynamic. I commented out the "dynamic" code.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Sub OpenGIP()

Dim ch As Long
ch = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")
'Opens Bloomberg window #2 (Note: <blp-n> - where n is [BB Window instance # - 1])
Call DDEExecute(ch, "<blp-1><home> MSFT US <EQUITY> GIP30 <GO>")
'Call DDEExecute(ch, "<blp-1><home> ActiveCell.Value & ' US' <EQUITY> GIP30 <GO>")
Call DDETerminate(ch)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Call DDEExecute(ch, "<blp-1><home> " & ActiveCell.value & " US <EQUITY> GIP30 <GO>")
```